# React Flux Get Api data from remote service

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am trying to follow the flux architecture from the facebook sample found at 
https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc

Where is this architecture would you call your api to get data from a remote service?

The AppContainer has a getState method which gets the get initial state of the store. This would be null since the database call hasn't happened yet. I could make the api call in the Action creator. But where do i trigger this action?

AppContainer.js

```
function getStores() {
    return [
        TodoStore
    ];
}

function getState() {
  return {
    todos: TodoStore.getState()
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an action dispatcher, that fires the fetch request and dispatches the action with the fetch result as payload. Handle this action dispatcher over via `mapDispatchToProps` and call it inside your component via `componentDidMount` cycle method.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I created a top level component and fire off the action there. mapDispatchToProps is redux right?

Answer (score 0):

you should create Actions class, that will have methods. This method will dispatch actions to store, and send ajax data.

example of one `Actions` class method:

```
changeCurrent(role: string): void {
    // Things to do right now
    dispatch(RolesActionID.ROLES_CHANGE_CURRENT, {
        role: role
    });

    let props: any = { Role: role };
    let data: any = formAjaxData("GetPrivileges", props, true);

    // Send ajax
    let post: any = $.post({ url: "/v1/json", data: data, contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8" })
        .done(function (result: string): void {
            dispatch(RolesActionID.ROLES_CHANGE_CURRENT_SUCCESS, {
                rolePrivileges: result,
                role: role
            });
        })

        .fail(function (result: any): void {
            // Fail actions
        });
};
```

so in fact you will have 2-3 dispatched events:

1. when action started  (we can disable SUBMIT button for expl)
2. when we got success ajax response
3. when we got failed ajax response (don't forget to enable SUBMIT button again)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Though I was unable to do multiple dispatches in an action. I get an error saying that you cannot do a dispatch when another dispatch is in progress.

Comment: this could be, if you done this method in "StoreClass". At the end you should have 2 classes:
1. NameStore;
2. NameActions;

NameStore - it is the one, that register to AppDispatcher, and is waiting for dispatched actions (u can't dispatch another actions here)

NameActions - it is separate class, it is used only to dispatch actions and send ajax.